# How do I compile my TypeScript code with import statements?

Tags: typescript, compilation, tsc

I'm making a project in TypeScript. I'm not too good with tsc and other stuff like that. I use import statements in my code. I really want to be able to compile to JavaScript without changing them. This is my tsconfig.json:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ESNext"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "ESNext",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "include": ["src", "Citation"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "kostegator",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "src/index.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only --poll ./src",
        "build": "tsc src/index.ts -w -esModuleInterop --resolveJsonModule",
        "test": "node dist/index.js --experimental-specifier-resolution=node"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "ProGamer2711",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/ms": "^0.7.31",
        "ts-node": "^10.1.0",
        "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "canvas": "^2.6.1",
        "discord.js": "^12.5.3",
        "gif-encoder-2": "^1.0.5",
        "mongoose": "^5.13.2",
        "ms": "^2.1.3",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: what issue are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

Since your post doesn't specify what issues you're actually running into. I'm going to assume you want to use the resulting JS in a browser environment. In that case you are going to need to bundle your code. `TSC` "only" transpiles your TS to JS, but it doesn't resolve any dependencies. There are many different bundle programs, however I usually use `rollup`.

Add these dependencies:

```
npm install rollup @rollup/plugin-typescript @rollup/plugin-commonjs @rollup/plugin-node-resolve
```

Add this config file next to your `package.json` file. Call the file `rollup.config.js`

```js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default [
  {
    input: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
      file: './dist/index.js',
      format: 'iife',
      name: "kostegator"
    },
    plugins: [
      typescript(),
      nodeResolve(),
      commonjs(),
    ],
  }
];
```

Then change your build script (in `package.json`) to:

```
rollup --config
```

If you want to see a usage example of these configs: https://github.com/Olian04/dnd-beyond-to-discord

Comment: Hello, I tried your answer. Now I'm getting this error:
`Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
                          ^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Programming\NodeJS\Discord bots\Kostegator\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at ...`

Comment: check comments. Also I have a lot of TS files. Do I have to write those things for them all?

Comment: @AlexanderShestakov why do you have the package type set to `module`? Unless you know exactly what that means then you likely don't want it. Remove the line `"type": "module"` from `package.json`.

Comment: I removes `"type": "module"` from `package.json`. That still didn't work. The error I'm getting is: `Error: Cannot find module '../src/Client'
Require stack: {path to file that I tried to run} {...}`. For context I'm requiring `./Client` because my Client class is there. There isn't a `Client` folder in `dist`. Should there be? Do I have to write similar code for every TS file?

Comment: @AlexanderShestakov you are going to have to show me your entire setup. I won't be able to help you effectively otherwise. Is it on github?

Comment: It's normally private but I'm going to change visibility in a second. Here's the link: [Kostegator](https://www.github.com/ProGamer2711/Kostegator)

Comment: @AlexanderShestakov ohh, it's a discord.js bot? Then you aren't running your code in the browser. Ignore my entire answer. Just use `ts-node ./src/index.ts`

Comment: I'm using it normally but I want to compile it and run it from node. This is because of previous issues. If you want to you can check out previous questions from me and see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @AlexanderShestakov then run `tsc`, followed by `node ./dist/index.js`

Comment: That was what I did at first. I got some errors to use require() instead of import and that thing about .cjs files

Comment: @AlexanderShestakov that error had nothing to do with `tsc`. It shouldn't occur now that you've removed `"type": "module"`.

Comment: I tried `tsc` again but it still didn't work. The error I'm getting is `import { Command } from "../../Interfaces";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: @AlexanderShestakov are you sure you've pushed your latest changes to git? because i pulled down your repo and it's throwing a lot of errors. However none of them is what you are describing. And once i fixed those errors (just following what the compiler complains about) then `tsc` runs without any errors... as expected.